# var's I keep declaring the same things over again

Tags: php, oop, function, global, private

Not sure if there is away to do what I want, I basically need to store the following information in a global var, and if they are being requested, then be able to fetch them from any public function without having to re-send it to the function that needs the information at current I am doing the following

```
public function savenewbusinesslead($tradingname, $companyname)
{
    $this->tradingname  = $tradingname;
    $this->companyname  = $companyname;
}

public function sendemail($email,$tradingname){
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->tradingname = $tradingname
}
```

What I want to do is the following

```
private function global($tradingname, $companyname){
     $this->tradingname = $tradingname;
     $this->companyname = $companyname;
}
public function savenewbusinesslead(){
     print $this->global->tradingname;
}
```

Comment: Use a class like `Test` and call it like `Test::sendemail()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference a global variable from within your methods, you need to use the global keyword, like this:

```
  //assuming $tradingname is defined ouside your method
public function savenewbusinesslead(){
   global $tradingname;
   print $tradingname;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Kinda, but how do I store the global var? is it just by putting $tradingname after the class function? or in its own function?

Comment: You can define the variable outside all functions, that'll make it global.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a static variable in your class to handle this.

More over there: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php